# Deleting items from list in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to remove an item from the product list. In my code, it deletes the other items, not the specific one that i want to delete.. I already assigned which id to delete but it doesn't. I  don't know why it deletes the others.. Please help. Thank you

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './Product';
import { PRODUCTLIST } from './ProductSupplier';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductDatabaseService {
selectedProduct: Product | undefined;
productList:Product[]=[];

getProductList(): Product[] {
    return PRODUCTLIST;
}

deleteProduct(prodCode: number) {
    const product = PRODUCTLIST.splice(prodCode);
    return product;
}

addProductData(code: number, name: string, price: number, details: string) {
    let newProduct = new Product(code, name, price, details);
    PRODUCTLIST.push(newProduct);
}

getProductByID(prodCode: number) {
    const product = PRODUCTLIST.find(s => s.prodCode === prodCode);
    return product;
}


constructor() { }
}
```

I used the splice method to remove

**Component class**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Product } from '../Product';
import { ProductDatabaseService } from '../product-database.service';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
selector: 'app-product-details',
templateUrl: './product-details.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./product-details.component.css']
})

export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
selectedProduct: Product | undefined;
productList: Product[] = [];
constructor(private productDBService: ProductDatabaseService,
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private location: Location,
private router: Router,
private router2: Router) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getProduct();
}

getProduct(): void {
    const prodCode = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('prodCode'));
    this.selectedProduct = this.productDBService.getProductByID(prodCode);
}

updateProduct(prodCode: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['update-product', prodCode]);
}

deleteProduct(code: number) {
    this.productDBService.deleteProduct(code);
}

}
```

HTML Code

```html
<div class="card" *ngIf="selectedProduct">
      <div class="card-header">
       <h2>{{selectedProduct.prodName | uppercase}} Details</h2>
      </div>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Product Code</th>
            <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Product Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Product Details</th>
            <th scope="col">Actions</th>
            <th scope="col">Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{selectedProduct.prodCode}}</th>
            <td>{{selectedProduct.prodName}}</td>
            <td>{{selectedProduct.prodPrice}}</td>
            <td>{{selectedProduct.prodDetails}}</td>
          <td><button (click)="updateProduct(selectedProduct.prodCode)" class ="btn btn-danger">Update</button></td>
          <td><button (click)="deleteProduct(selectedProduct.prodCode)" class ="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
          </tr>
    
          </tbody>
          </table>
    
          <div class="vstack gap-2 col-md-4 mx-auto">
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
           
          </div>
          <div>
          <a  (click)="navigateBack()" class="btn btn-dark">Go Back</a>
          </div>

  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do 2 things:

1. Find the index of the item that you want to remove
2. Pass second parameter to `splice()` that specifies the number of items that should be removed. In this use case, second parameter should be `1`, since you want to remove only one item.

```js
const index = PRODUCTLIST.findIndex((product: any) => product.prodCode === prodCode);
if (index !== -1) PRODUCTLIST.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: Not sure if `prodCode` is an `index` of the item in the array, i think it is an ID actually, so your code will not work as expected, but second parameter is a must anyway

Comment: Yup, you are right. I was not sure about the `prodCode` parameter. I assumed it's index since `splice()` function.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this code but it deletes the next prodCode. Like instead of deleting prodCode 2, it deletes the prodCode 3

Comment: I updated my answer. Can  you try it again?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're using splice the wrong way. To remove with the splice method an item you would need to specify the amount of items you want to delete/add.
In addition to that, the first argument of the splice method is the INDEX of the item to remove. So before calling the splice method. So you would do something like:

```
var array = [{prodCode: 20, name: "Product 1"}, {prodCode: 21, name: "Product 2"}, {prodCode: 22, name: "Product 3"}]
//we get the index of the item to remove
var indexToRemove = array.findIndex(product => product.prodCode == 21)
//we splice the array from the index of the item to remove of 1 item (the single item to remove)
array.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
```

here is a simple jsFiddle, just using the console to print the result:

https://jsfiddle.net/baduCleo/fhr3kzc4/